Dart: microsecond in datetime always 0
Always when i want to use microsecond of DateTime it is always return 0.
So i made this test and set microsecond to 345:
void main () {
  DateTime duration = DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 345);

  print(duration.microsecond);
  print(duration.millisecond);

  print(duration);
}

and this is what i got:
0
0
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000

and if i set microsecond to >=500 (exp : 675), this is the result:
0
1
2024-01-01 00:00:00.001

Is this bug or i am missing somethings ?

I think the VM can represent microseconds, but Javascript cannot.  You didn't mention what platform you're on... can you clarify?

yes i tested it via https://dartpad.dev/

It works fine if you don't run it on Web.
The "issue" is that Flutter Web rounds microseconds in DateTime objects because its internal time thingy can't handle values between microseconds. It just chops it off to the nearest whole microsecond.
For super precise microsecond fun, use the Duration class instead. It lets you create durations with specific microsecond values, no rounding required!
Code
Duration duration = Duration(microseconds: 345);
print(duration.inMicroseconds); // Prints 345

